# Using emscripten how to get C++ uint8_t array to JS Blob or UInt8Array

Tags: c++, emscripten, arraybuffer

In emscripten C++, I have

```
class MyClass {
public:
   MyClass() {}
   std::shared_ptr<std::vector<uint8_t>> buffer;
   int getPtr() {
      return (int)(buffer->data());
   }
   int getLength() {
      return buffer->size();
   }
};
EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS() {
    class_<MyClass>("MyClass").constructor()
      .function("getLength",&MyClass::getLength)
      .function("getPtr",&MyClass::getPtr,
                allow_raw_pointers());
}
```

I can invoke getLength() and getPtr() from JS but I'm don't know how to get JS to treat it as an ArrayBuffer for download as a Blob.

How can I get the buffer data into JS in a form where I can then download it using code similar to https://github.com/kennethjiang/js-file-download/blob/master/file-download.js.

Comment: So you mean you want convert `std::vector<uint8_t> buffer` to ArrayBuffer in JS side?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Currently WebAssembly only defines basic number types to communicate between JS and WASM. There is no Object types  nor Array types. [This is the WebAssembly's design goal.](https://webassembly.org/docs/rationale/) Emscripten have done some hacks to make C++ Class <=> JS bindings, but they are not WASM standard.

### WebAssembly.Memory()

BUT there is a way around this to get the array. JS has direct access to the internal memory of WASM modules, even without an API. WASM has a linear memory model and the linear memory is interfaced through [`WebAssembly.Memory()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WebAssembly/Memory). `WebAssembly.Memory()` is a single ArrayBuffer [`WebAssembly.Memory.buffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WebAssembly/Memory/buffer) where your WASM module uses as the heap memory region and where memory allocations (e.g. `malloc()`) happen.

### 1. Accessing it as UInt8Array

What does it mean? It means that **the pointer (integer in JS side) you get from `getPtr()` is actually an offset to `WebAssembly.Memory.buffer`.**

Emscripten automatically generates JS (this is generated from a template called [preamble.js](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/incoming/src/preamble.js)) code that create `WebAssembly.Memory()`. You can search Emscripten-generated code yourself and should be able find out a line similar [to this line](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/3e193554813643458a506e299c49cbf6c53fe4e9/src/preamble.js#L1222):

```
Module['wasmMemory'] = new WebAssembly.Memory({ 'initial': TOTAL_MEMORY / WASM_PAGE_SIZE, 'maximum': TOTAL_MEMORY / WASM_PAGE_SIZE });
```

So you can access to the ArrayBuffer used by your WASM module through `Module['wasmMemory'].buffer`:

```
let instance = new Module.MyClass();

// ... Do something

let ptr = instance.getPtr();
let size = instance.getLength();
// You can use Module['env']['memory'].buffer instead. They are the same.
let my_uint8_buffer = new Uint8Array(Module['wasmMemory'].buffer, ptr, size);
```

### 2. Emscripten `HEAPU8`

Alternatively, Emscripten offers [an official way to access the heap memory region as typed arrays](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/api_reference/preamble.js.html?highlight=heapu8#type-accessors-for-the-memory-model): `HEAPU8`,`HEAPU16`, `HEAPU32`, and etc. as defined [here](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/3e193554813643458a506e299c49cbf6c53fe4e9/src/preamble.js#L895-L904). So you can do like this:

```
let instance = new Module.MyClass();

// ... Do something

let ptr = instance.getPtr();
let size = instance.getLength();
let my_uint8_buffer = new Uint8Array(Module.HEAPU8.buffer, ptr, size);
```

Using `HEAPU8` would be safer, since `HEAPU8` is documented whereas the attribute name of `Module['wasmMemory']` is kinda undocumented and may be subject to change; but they do the same thing.

### 3. Using `emscripten::val` (C++ only)

Emscripten also provides a class called [`emscripten::val`](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/embind.html#using-val-to-transliterate-javascript-to-c) for C++ developers to interact between JS and C++. This abstracts any JS/C++ types for convenience. You can get the array using this.

This is the example taken from [the documentation](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/embind.html#memory-views) and Glenn's comment:

```
#include <emscripten/bind.h>
#include <emscripten/val.h>

emscripten::val getInt8Array() {
    return emscripten::val(
       emscripten::typed_memory_view(buffer->size(),
                                     buffer->data()));
}

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS() {
    function("getInt8Array", &getInt8Array);
}
```

Then you can call `getInt8Array()` in JS side to get the typed array.

### Conclusion

There are 3 options suggested here to get the array from WASM. In any way, I think you should understand the concepts of `WebAssembly.Memory` and things behind option 1, because this is the lowest level to get an array from WASM, and, most importantly, **this is unmanaged and unsafe memory access so that it's easy to corrupt data** when the object is freed or modified in C/C++ side. The knowledge of the low-level implications is required for this specific case.

Comment: These are great suggestions and helps my understanding of the linkage.  Looking at [memory-views](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/embind.html#memory-views) I found I could also use `val getInt8Array() { return val(typed_memory_view(buffer->size(),buffer->data())); }` and just call getInt8Array() from JS.  Would it make sense to add this to your answer for completeness?

Comment: @Glenn I didn't know about that thing before, since I have done only C for Emscripten code, but it looks like `emscripten::val` worth studying for C++ devs. I will add this thing too.

Comment: @RedRidingHood Did you make a new array in JS side? A new array should be created in C++ side, via a wrapper function.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just solved this in a hacky workaround. Defined a custom `Module.print` to capture your data via `printf` statements. My example:

C++

```cpp
bool first = true;
for (auto i : settings)
{
    if (!first)
    {
        printf(",");
    }
    first = false;
    printf("%u", i);
}
printf("\n");
```

(This will print something that looks like `1,255,76,31`)

JS: (The below needs to be defined before the `<script>` tag that contains the emscripten output `.js`)

```js
let arrayFromC;
var Module = {
  preRun: [],
  postRun: [],
  print: function (printOutput) {
    arrayFromC = printOutput.split(",");
  },
};
```