# Understanding the Emscripten trace collector output

Tags: emscripten

I'm using the [trace API in emscripten](https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/trace.h.html) to check memory allocations in my code.

In the [trace allocator](https://github.com/waywardmonkeys/emscripten-trace-collector) overview, the "Allocation summary" is always increasing, into the GB, while the "Memory usage" is stable below 50MB.  When looking at the individual frames, the number of "Alloc" and "Free" are the same (except on startup), but the number of bytes allocated and released is not.

Am I reading this wrong? Is this a problem in the configuration of the traces?

Answer (score 0):

All of the weird things happen because you cannot really keep track of memory allocations of WebAssembly (or Emscripten) using JS engine system tools. In other words, the heap is managed by WebAssembly user code, not by JS engine like V8.

You probably want to check [my explanation of the WebAssembly memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53602955/using-emscripten-how-to-get-c-uint8-t-array-to-js-blob-or-uint8array/53605865#53605865). WebAssembly has a single linear memory region called [`WebAssembly.Memory`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WebAssembly/Memory). This is actually a single large JS ArrayBuffer [WebAssembly.Memory.buffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WebAssembly/Memory/buffer) which is the only memory region (except stack) WebAssembly module can touch by design. While WebAssembly cannot touch any memory outside of that single ArrayBuffer, it can do anything with this buffer. So most of WebAssembly binaries use the buffer as a heap region.

WebAssembly 1.0 does not specify any kinds of built-in user library including memory managements. This means that every C/C++ code compiled to WebAssembly has to have its own implementation of `malloc()`, whereas the host system -the JS engine in this context- has no idea what happens inside of the heap.

So regardless of how much you allocated and freed the heap inside your Emscripten code, in the V8 perspective memory usage will remain stable because it already allocated the whole ArrayBuffer and gave away to the Emscripten instance.

The only exception is that the WebAssembly instance may request the JS engine to [increase the size of the ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WebAssembly/Memory/grow) as it needs more heap, just like `sbrk` in C/C++ context. So the JS engine allocation only tends to grow until it reaches the maximum size of [`WebAssembly.Memory()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WebAssembly/Memory#Parameters) you (or auto-generated JS code done by Emscripten) specify.

Comment: I'm using a Emscripten tool to track allocations, not a browser dev tool. This does not answer my question.