# How does WebAssembly <-> JavaScript memory interaction work with multiple Typed Arrays?

Tags: javascript, emscripten, webassembly, typed-arrays

I've got a simple c function.

```c
void fill(float *a, float *b)
{
  a[0] = 1;
  b[0] = 2;
}

int main()
{
    float a[1];
    float b[1];

    fill(a, b);

    printf("%f\n", a[0]);
    printf("%f\n", b[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

That gives me

```sh
1.000000
2.000000
```

Now I'm trying to do the same but from JavaScript via WebAssembly.

```js
var wasmModule = new WebAssembly.Module(wasmCode);
var wasmInstance = new WebAssembly.Instance(wasmModule, wasmImports);

const a = new Float32Array(wasmInstance.exports.memory.buffer, 0, 1)
const b = new Float32Array(wasmInstance.exports.memory.buffer, 4, 1)

wasmInstance.exports.fill(a, b)

log(a)
log(b)
```

Here is the wasm fiddle https://wasdk.github.io/WasmFiddle/?19x523

This time `a` is `[2]` and b is `[0]`. I think I'm doing something wrong with the memory. I assume both `a` and `b` point to the beginning of the memory. That's why `a` is first `[1]` and immediately afterwards `[2]`. I though the offsets from `new Float32Array(wasmInstance.exports.memory.buffer, 4, 1)` where the offset is `4` are somehow translated to WebAssembly.

How can I achieve that `a` and `b` actually use different memory? Thank you. I'm really stuck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a problem with this exported function call:

> wasmInstance.exports.fill(a, b)

`a` and `b` are JS `Float32Array` objects. **Never assume any JS objects will be translated to any C data types automagically.** Although a JS TypedArray behaves similar to C array, TypedArray is still a JS object that basically is a key-value storage, then how C can access JS object's field? C has no idea how to deal with a JS object.

### WebAssembly Types

Okay, let's look at it more closely in a lower level in WebAssembly. Here's the compiled result of `void fill(float *a, float *b)`:

```
 (func $fill (; 0 ;) (param $0 i32) (param $1 i32)
  (i32.store
   (get_local $0)
   (i32.const 1065353216)
  )
  (i32.store
   (get_local $1)
   (i32.const 1073741824)
  )
 )
```

I won't go over details, but at least it is easy to figure out this function `$fill` needs two parameters of `i32` type: `(param $0 i32) (param $1 i32)`. **So `fill()` expects numbers, not TypedArrays, as parameters**. WebAssembly defines [the following types](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/syntax/types.html) as function parameter types and return types: `i32`, `i64`, `f32`, `f64`, basically 32/64 bit intergers/floats. There is no other types like JS key-value store, no even array types.

Therefore, **whatever languages you use in Wasm side, you are not supposed to pass any JS types other than numbers to functions under `wasmInstance.exports` directly.** Many languages like Golang, Rust, and Emscripten C++ (not C) provides interfaces for seamless type translation by wrapping around exported functions in JS side and by hacking around those number types and Wasm memory addresses (so they need a well-defined ABI). However, you still must pass only number types if you access the exported functions directly through [`WebAssembly.Instance.exports`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WebAssembly/Instance/exports).

### Accessing Arrays

So then what integer value you need to pass to `fill()`? Well I think you are already close to the answer in the question, as you correctly set offsets for the arrays. You need to pass value of C pointers as integers. **In the Wasm linear memory, a C pointer is an offset address to the Wasm memory**. So you need to slightly change the code like this:

```
var wasmModule = new WebAssembly.Module(wasmCode);
var wasmInstance = new WebAssembly.Instance(wasmModule, wasmImports);

const ptrA = 0; // Yeah it's the same value as NULL, I'd avoid using zero...
const ptrB = 4;

const a = new Float32Array(wasmInstance.exports.memory.buffer, ptrA, 1)
const b = new Float32Array(wasmInstance.exports.memory.buffer, ptrB, 1)

wasmInstance.exports.fill(ptrA, ptrB)

log(a)
log(b)
```

Now you will get the value you want ;)

Related: [Using emscripten how to get C++ uint8_t array to JS Blob or UInt8Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53602955/using-emscripten-how-to-get-c-uint8-t-array-to-js-blob-or-uint8array/53605865#53605865)

Comment: This  is  awesome ! Thank you. It finally all makes sense.